# Uniq hash values

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash whose values are arrays as follows:

```
hash = {
  "key1" => [object11, object12, object13],
  "key2" => [object21, object22, object23]
}
```

All objects within an array are of the same class, which has attribute `source`. If `object11` and `object12` have similar `source` values, I want to delete one of them, either `object11` or `object12`. I want to check the objects within an array and thus delete the duplicate ones. By duplicate I mean those with existing attribute value.

I tried to do:

```
hash.values.map(&:source).uniq
```

but it didn't work. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: What return are you looking for? the Hash with the duplicates removed or an Array? for an Array it would just be `hash.values.map{|a| a.uniq{|s| s.source}}` this will return a 2D Array like `[[object11,object13],[object21,object22,object23]]` based on your description.

Comment: I would like to have Hash with the duplicates removed.

Comment: Do you want to mutate the original `hash` object or not?

Comment: yes, I would like that

Comment: in that case your answer is already posted by @jkeuhlen and could be shortened to what I posted in the comment. As long as you want the objects isolated to their corresponding key. Meaning there can be duplicate source objects under different keys. If you want unique source objects across all keys please specify so the answer can be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely could be shortened but here is the long way that comes to mind for me:

```
hash.each do |key, values_array|
  hash[key] = values_array.uniq { |v| v.source }
end
```

What this is doing is iterating over each key in the hash along with the array stored with it. Then it forces uniqueness based on the `source` attribute for each object in the array, and stores it back in the hash at that key position.

EDIT:
As mentioned by @engineersmnky in the comments, it can be shortened to:

```
hash.each {|_,v| v.uniq!(&:source) }
```

Comment: You are correct that it can be shortend(if we are mutating `hash`) this can be `hash.each {|_,v| v.uniq!(&:source) }`

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks, I added that in to my answer as well.